Can JB Weld Plastic Bonder be used with fiberglass mesh?
There is a fairly large crack in the housing of our dishwasher. I was going to try JB plastic bonder and I thought some mesh would help make it stronger and cover a wider area.
Has anyone done anything similar?


Any idea why it cracked? If there's stress from the hinge being sloppy it'll just crack up again.

Your suggestion and/or plastic welding should work, for a time.  Checking for movement as the door opens/closes will help.  Might google make and model to see if other people have the same problem.

I broke it, I was lifting onto a table to wire it up etc. And the door wasn't latched and fell open I didn't think anything of it until I installed it water started gushing

I'll let you know if it works

Having it welded is probably the best approach - take it it to a plastic welder.

I took the side rails off last night and the crack is longer than I thought. I'm just not sure it's worth it at this point. I think I'll try to find another used one. Thanks to all
